# Determine whether the given the orthogonal matrix represents a roation or reflextion...?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal, orthogonality

I am given the matrix
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -1/2 & \sqrt{3}/2 \\
        -\sqrt{3}/2 & -1/2\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I think this is a reflection because I tied sketching a rough graph. However, I'm not sure how to find the line of reflection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As $det(A)=1$, it is a rotation. Reflexion changes orientation, which would yield $det(A)=-1$. (This argument is valid only in the 2d-case.)

To find out the angle of rotation, compute the angle between $e_1$ and $Ae_1$.

If $A$ would be a reflection, the line of reflection is given by the eigenvector to the eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: Okay, so I need to calculate the determinant to figure out if it is rotation and reflection. However, how do i find the angle of rotation and the line of reflection accordingly?

Comment: The eigenvalues of a reflection of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are always $+1, -1$. By construction the line of reflection is the $(+1)$-eigenspace.

Comment: One last question, I find the angle by cos$\theta$ = u.v/ (||u|| ||v||) where u = e1 and v= Ae1?

Comment: Exactly, thats the definition of an angle between vectors by means of an inner product.